OpenSSH SSH Server won't start on Windows Server 2019 after Windows Updates
I have two Windows Server 2019 hosts that cannot start the OpenSSH SSSH Server service after the following Windows updates were installed:
.NET Framework 4.8
October 2024 Cumulative Update
Malicious Software Removal Tool
The Date Modified changed to last night on all files in C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH:
OpenSSH Directory
Attempting to start the service results in:
"Windows could not start the OpenSSH SSH Service on Local Computer. Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly"
There is nothing in the SSH log file when attempting to start. The Event Log gives not helpful details that I can find other than saying "The OpenSSH SSH Server service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 8 time(s)."

A similar issue has been disclosed on Stack Overflow, so check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319140/error-1067-on-start-openssh-by-net-start-opensshd-in-windows-cmd

Add the error message when starting from PowerShell, which may help search engine indexing. Edit: code block didn't work, odd.
PS> Start-Service sshd
Start-Service : Failed to start service 'OpenSSH SSH Server (sshd)'.
At line:1 char:1

Start-Service sshd

  + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
 ServiceCommandException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand



The permissions on the LOG directory was wrong.
I removed the LOG folder, restarted the service and everything started working again. The LOG folder was automatically re-created.
But.. if you enter the logfile (as admin user), and after accepting "you need admin permissions to access this folder", your username end up in the list op users with read permissions.
after that, the deamon won't start again.
removing the user from the security list of the LOG folder solves this, and the service starts again. :(

From Microsoft December 2024 monthly update, known issues section:
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/5048661
Following the installation of the October 2024 security update, some customers report that the OpenSSH (Open Secure Shell) service fails to start, preventing SSH connections. The service fails with no detailed logging, and manual intervention is required to run the sshd.exe process.
Workaround:
Customers can temporarily resolve the issue by updating permissions (ACLs) on the affected directories. Follow these steps:

Open PowerShell as an Administrator.

Update the permissions for C:\ProgramData\ssh and C:\ProgramData\ssh\logs to allow full control for SYSTEM and the Administrators group, while allowing read access for Authenticated Users. You can restrict read access to specific users or groups by modifying the permissions string if needed.
Use the following commands to update the permissions:


$directoryPath = "C:\ProgramData\ssh"  
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $directoryPath  
$sddlString = "O:BAD:PAI(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;AU)"   
$securityDescriptor = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RawSecurityDescriptor $sddlString $acl.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm($securityDescriptor.GetSddlForm("All"))  
Set-Acl -Path $directoryPath -AclObject $acl


Repeat the above steps for C:\ProgramData\ssh\logs.


Win32 OpenSSH Issue #2282 Opened October 8, indicating the issue began with version 9.4:
v9.4.0.0p1 and later enforce permissions on the logs folder, leading to undiagnosable crashes of the service after Windows Update #2282
https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/2282
Linked to this pull request:
add check for prog data folder permissions during sshd service startup #686
https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/pull/686

Same here. Noticed the problem since recent update/patch. Able to start from command line, but not start as service. Indeed remove "LOG" folder fixed the problem for me. Thanks.

If you've ever open C:\ProgramData\ssh\logs directory from Explorer, and choose Continue in the "Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder" dialog its permission will change, and sshd service can't be started after that. I think someone should file a bug report to Microsoft.

You just saved my sanity, thank you !!! This issue is encountered by many but until here no solutions after hours of digging and searching

Pretty much the cause of my issues. Tried for many days with no luck and the error messages are not helpful at all. Uninstalled OpenSSH. Renamed my ProgramData/ssh subdir. Rebooted (just in case). Resinstalled OpeenSSH and it is working like it used to do.

OMG this was crazy. I spent ~3h to check ports, networks etc. Thanks

Acording to CVE-2024-43615, the KB5044277 also adresses te mentioned OpenSSH vulnerability.
Might be worth to have a look at it.
However, explicit information about the update in connection with OpenSSH is still rare. Maybe more information will follow but I am pretty sure that your problem has something to do with that.

I tested this out, and logs directory permissions seems to be the problem as Wig-B found out. I can add groups with Read&execute, List folder contents and Read permissions to logs directory security and thighs seems to work.
Default permissions are
SYSTEM (full control)
Administrators (full control)

I believe it's a permission error. Without changing the permission in question, I could start the service by running C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sshd.exe directly( from PowerShell). But only after this permission change can I Start-Service sshd.

tl;dr: delete or rename %programData%/ssh (for example: C:\ProgramData\ssh)

When I try net start sshd, I get the error as below
The OpenSSH Server service is starting.
The OpenSSH Server service could not be started.
A system error has occurred.
System error 1067 has occurred.
The process terminated unexpectedly.

I tried many methods, including restarting the service,
checking read and write permissions, and even considered reinstalling.
However, I finally discovered that simply deleting (or renaming) the %programData%/ssh directory and running net start sshd again could solve the problem.

Thanks for this contribution, but this is more or less the same as saying "I uninstalled the program and re-installed the program and now it works."  Deleting ProgramData\ssh deletes all settings, etc.

I thank you so much ! I only rename the %programData%/ssh in ssh.old and the service start again! Good Job!

@Mark Williams I uninstalled the program and it didn't worked because the %programData%/ssh existed.

I encountered this on Server 2022. With help from this StackOverflow answer and Gustavo's comment there, to fix this:

Right-click on the C:\ProgramData\ssh\logs folder and select Properties.
Click on the Security tab, Advanced button and remove all users except SYSTEM and Administrators. Alternatively, downgrade other users to read-only.

The OpenSSH service should start now.
What happened (how to break it again)
If you're logged in as an administrator and double-click on the "logs" folder, you'll be offered the option to "Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder":

If you click Continue, the user you are logged in as is granted Full Control permissions on the logs folder. Apparently the October 2024 update makes a change that will refuse to start the OpenSSH service if any "extra" users have write permissions to the logs folder. However as @Kivioja Antti's answer reports, downgrading that user to read-only (Read & execute, List folder contents, Read) also fixes the problem.

I just solved this.

Remove-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
Rename C:\ProgramData\ssh to C:\ProgramData\\_ssh
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
Start-Service sshd
Stop-Service sshd
Delete c:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config
Copy C:\ProgramData\\_ssh\sshd_config to C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config
Start-Service sshd

Not sure if 1 and 3 are needed.

This worked for me without steps 1 and 3.

Same issue, but on windows 10.
To solve it:

rename the C:\ProgramData\ssh\logs folder to logs2.
restart service.....

That will create a new logs folder and it will work fine

if you rename it to logs2 you can also delete it

@djdomi yep. renaming is necessary to keep the information if it has been

Had the same issue.
But the log-directory alone was not enough. You also have to make sure only SYSTEM can read all of the private-keys in C:\ProgramData\ssh\
Also if you get an Access denied at the Add-WindowsCapability you may need to reboot the server.
